# Counting relationships based on a distinct relationship propriety

Tags: neo4j

On each relationship, I have a propriety SAB which has 10 different values. I would like to count on distinct SAB propriety the number of distinct relationships and display it as a list.

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) WITH n,m,collect(r)[1..] AS rels, r.SAB AS SAB  FOREACH(distinct SAB IN rels | count(r)) return count(r), rels;
```

I tried to create a query which will do this for me, but i dont have enugh knowledge.

I would like to have a list showing

```
type1(SAB)  COUNT(HAS_CHILD) 1000
type1(SAB)  COUNT(HAS_DESCENDANT) 2000
type2(SAB)  COUNT(HAS_CHILD) 2198
type2(SAB)  COUNT(HAS_DESCENDANT) 81924
....
UNTIL TYPE 10 SAB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if i am right, you want query something like this

```
MATCH (n)-[r]->(m)
RETURN DISTINCT r.SAB, TYPE(r), COUNT(r)
```

RESULT

```
    r.SAB    TYPE(r)           COUNT(r)
    sab01    HAS_CHILD         1
    sab02    HAS_DESCENDANT    2
    sab02    HAS_CHILD         1
```

Comment: Just to note DISTINCT isn't needed here, since when you perform an aggregation the grouping key (all the non-aggregation variables) become distinct automatically.